# c++ nonconst-const-overloaded method choosing

Tags: c++, constants, overloading

I have const-overloaded methods in my class:

```
class A{
  public:
     typedef int data[10];

           data& operator[](int index);
     const data& operator[](int index) const;
}
```

This class is implementing copy-on-write for its internal data. I figured that since i am allowing to access data directly, i must create copy of shared data (if it is shared obviously) on every use of `operator[]`, but not `operator[] const`. However, even if code is using operator[] for reading data, but object itself is not declared as const, it will still cause creating copy, as operator[] will be used. Is there any syntax that would let me allow to choose which of those operators i am calling?

Comment: If you allow people to save the returned reference and use it later, you will also have to disable future sharing once a reference is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: `const_cast<A const&>(anAObj)[5]`.

Answer (score 1):

Why does the operator return a `data&` rather than an `int&` that references a single item?

That being said your options include:

- Always do the copy even if it turns out to be unneeded.
- Use the operator for read or write, and a named method (`GetRef` for example) for the other one.
- Cast the object to `const` at the use point: `static_cast<const A&>(obj)[index]`.

Comment: I am returning `data&` so i can have two-dimensional arrays with bracket operators on them in my object like `A a;` `a[1][2]=3;`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Proxy class to substitute the return value of both methods. Then, in the Proxy class you can handle reads and writes appropriately. Here's code that should compile to demonstrate the idea (working with an array of unsigned integers):

```
typedef unsigned int UINT;
```

class A {

```
class Proxy {
public:

    Proxy(const UINT &number): _number(number) {}

    const Proxy &operator=(const Proxy &obj) {
        cout << "Writting...\n";
        _number = obj._number;
        return *this;
    }

    operator const UINT &() const {
        cout << "Reading...\n";
        return _number;
    }

private:

    UINT _number;
};
```

public:

```
A(UINT *array): _array(array) {}

Proxy operator[](int index) {
    return _array[index];
}
const Proxy operator[](int index) const {
    return _array[index];
}
```

private:

```
UINT *_array;
```

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

```
UINT myArray[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

A a(myArray);        // Normal A object

UINT num1 = a[1];    // Reading fine
a[1] = num1;         // Writting fine

const A ca(myArray); // Constant A object

UINT num2 = ca[1];   // Reading fine
ca[1] = num2;        // Writting NOT fine (compilation error)

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Idea is nice, but as it is visible from my code i want to have possiblity to make it work with multi-dimensional arrays - it is still possible, but as number of dimensions grows it becomes messy and there seems not to be easy generalization to n-dimensions. (With my approach i can typedef data to be n-1 dimensional array and see my object as n-dimensional array then).

Answer (score 0):

No, unless you cast the reference/pointer to a constant. Or create a constant copy.

```
A a;
const_cast<const A &> (a)[0] /*.foo ()*/;
```

Comment: Well a "No, unless" is equivalent to a "Yes", isn't it ? ;)

Comment: @ereOn: I think it depends. In this case I meant it to sound more like a conjunction to highlight the possibility of exception rather than a well established rule meaning that there is such syntax but using it all over the code will not make a user happy. In fact, what I thought replying at the moment of writing the answer is that I'd implement copy-on-write with different interface where proxy to data is always constant unless copied and underlying data is mutable. But that was too much of a thought so I decided to simply state the "bad" syntax and get away with it but your caught me :-D

Answer (score 0):

implement `data& at(size_t i);` and `const data& cat(size_t);` functions, so you can invoke `cat()` on non-const objects to enforce constness of returned data.

Comment: that's something that i would gladly do if not the fact that i am using `operator[]`, and therefore cannot add letters or anything to the name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing copy-on-write, then you should not define those subscription operators at all. A client that calls the `const` version of the subscription method for an object `x` is not allowed to subsequently use that reference to modify a component of `x`, but the reference should still reflect the changes that other clients make to (that component of) `x`. But his is not going to happen with a copy-on-write strategy, since the change will happen in a different copy than the reference points to.

Also two clients that call the non-const subscription operator with the same index should get (modifyable) references to the *same* `data` object; but they won't, because two seperate copies will have been made when the subscription operators were called.

Instead you could have a subscription method that returns `data` by value. This avoids creating the illusion of obtaining an alias for a component of `x` (which as I argued *must be* illusory when copy-on-write is implemented). You could also provide a single method that modifies a component of `x` (rather than splitting this operation into a  subscription followed by assignment to the reference so obtained), which would either internally make a copy, or just modify a component in place if this copy was already made. This would hide from clients the use of a copy-on-write implementation.

More generally, exposing methods that return references to internal objects, whether `const` or not, is exposing the implementation detail that such objects exist at all. This limits the freedom of changing the implementation later, for instance to compress the data or to store it elsewhere than in memory.